Error running dir /p in VSCode Terminal - dir /p equivalent in PowerShell?
When I run dir /p in VSCode terminal, I get:
PS C:\Users\moren\source\repos\TrentonTompkins.com> dir /p
dir : Cannot find path 'C:\p' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir /p
+ ~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\p:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

It works in Command Prompt. There dir /p returns 1 page of items, which is nice if you have 1000 items and actually want to read them.
dir /p doesn't work in Windows 10 PowerShell. I am guessing VSCode uses PowerShell instead of cmd.exe.
Is there a way to do dir /p in PowerShell? I tried trying help dir, but it doesn't appears to have an option to only return a set number of results.
Should I just set my terminal in VSCode to cmd.exe? The only reason I can think to use PowerShell is that I can wget, but even that isn't real wget, because you have to use the -O option to actually save the file. I think I might switch the default terminal to cmd.exe, install wget for Windows and all it to my path, and if I need PowerShell, just run PowerShell.
I tried cmd dir /p, I didn't know I need the /c flag to feed it a command. I changed my terminal to cmd in VSCode, now I might change it back, lol.

In PowerShell dir is an alias for Get-ChildItem which does not have a command line switch /p.  ‍♂️

You can pipe to more.com dir | more


PowerShell equivalent of dir /p would be:
Get-ChildItem | Out-Host -Paging

Or shorter version:
dir | oh -p

As Olaf noted, dir in PowerShell is an alias for Get-ChildItem:
Get-Alias dir

# CommandType     Name                       Version    Source
# -----------     ----                       -------    ------
# Alias           dir -> Get-ChildItem

If you wanted to run the original dir command you'd need to use cmd /c:
cmd /c dir /p

